# How to align columns in git to improve formatting?

Tags: git, format, git-branch

I wanted to improve the formatting of my "git branch" command, where I added logic to include the **commit date** and **commit user**.

> git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:bold yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) %(color:green)%(committerdate)%(color:reset) - %(contents:subject) %(color:dim white) - %(authorname)%(color:reset)'

[image]

Is there anyway of improving the formatting from the first (actual) output, into the second (desired) output?

This is not an urgent thing at all, but a nice to have. I've played with the git format, but my knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `%(align)` format option, like this :

```
%(align:width=<number of chars>) <column to align> %(end)
```

which in your example would give

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(align:width=15)%(color:bold yellow)%(refname:short)%(end)%(color:reset) %(color:green)%(committerdate)%(color:reset) - %(contents:subject) %(color:dim white) - %(authorname)%(color:reset)'
```

It does the job, despite offering no dynamic value for the alignment, which would be nice but maybe not necessary, depending on your context.

Comment: It crashes with: `fatal: improper format entered align:width=15`.

Comment: just need to remove the `width=`, namely `$(align:15)`.

Comment: From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-align) : *For brevity, the "width=" and/or "position=" prefixes **may** be omitted, and bare <width> and <position> used instead.*. Both syntaxes are fine.